# How to get the Cartesian product of 2 columns by row

Tags: pyspark

I have some difficulities that if there's a spark dataframe and there is a column called "id" and another column called "friends"

```
+---+--------------------+
| id|             friends|
+---+--------------------+
|  0|[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6...|
|  1|[48, 53, 54, 73, ...|
|  2|[20, 115, 116, 14...|
|  3|[9, 25, 26, 67, 7...|
|  4|[78, 152, 181, 19...|
|  5|[87, 122, 156, 15...|
|  6|[89, 95, 147, 219...|
|  7|[22, 31, 38, 65, ...|
|  8|[91, 110, 193, 20...|
|  9|[21, 25, 26, 30, ...|
| 10|[67, 142, 169, 20...|
| 13|[21, 26, 56, 59, ...|
| 14|[20, 28, 41, 115,...|
| 16|[29, 82, 118, 172...|
| 17|[19, 41, 111, 115...|
| 19|[41, 89, 112, 115...|
| 20|[41, 44, 111, 115...|
| 21|[25, 26, 31, 39, ...|
| 22|[87, 158, 168, 18...|
| 23|[51, 61, 83, 99, ...|
+---+--------------------+
```

How can I get the cartesian product for each row?
For instance, the first row we should get (0,1) (0,2) (0,3)..etc
second row should get (1,48) (1,53)..

Comment: You should have a look at [`explode`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.functions.explode.html) function

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.